# How can I secure the connection between my android app and the web server

Tags: java, android, android-studio, encryption, communication

So Basically I'm building an android app that needs to communicate critical information with the web server, I need encryption method suggestions on top of https to improve the security and how can I use keystore to generate the keys? And also how can we securely store the keys on the web server?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Isn't https enough?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I prefer an end to end encryption...

Comment: https *is* e2ee between your app and your web server. What's between them? Or isn't the web server the other end of the communication? If that's the case you might want to [edit] your post and better explain your architecture. In any case you may want to explain *why* https is not a good fit, otherwise people might suggest solutions with the same pitfalls you're trying to avoid by not choosing the obvious solution.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thank you very much for your collaboration, there is no devices between the app and the server, so you find that adding another layer of security is not a good practice?

Comment: I'm not saying it's bad practice (although, reinventing security protocols usually *is* bad practice), I'm just wondering whether it's actually necessary or whether you might be over-complicating things.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I'm honestly a little bit complicating the things because the data that will be transferred is so critical

Comment: "Critical" doesn't sound like there is a proper security analysis present to define what security requirements and risks exist.